# Incorporate hyperlink and link in script for Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

I am currently trying desperately to include a hyperlink in my script that, after executing the script, the hyperlink as it is here should be placed in cell C16. The same would be for C17-C19 and in G19 again.

```
function AlteFahrerdatenLeeren(){ 
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="C7:C15"; 
  sheet.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="C20"; 
  sheet1.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="G6:G7"; 
  sheet2.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet3=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="G9"; 
  sheet3.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet4=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="G11:G17"; 
  sheet4.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet5=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="G20"; 
  sheet5.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet5=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="N16:N17"; 
  sheet5.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet6=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="Q10:R10"; 
  sheet6.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet7=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="S6"; 
  sheet7.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet8=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="O22:S32"; 
  sheet8.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet9=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="G35:S50"; 
  sheet9.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  var sheet10=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var destination="B53:S91"; 
  sheet10.getRange(destination).setValue(""); 
  **var SS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var sheet=ss.getRange(C16).setValue(HYPERLINK("https://erfurter-fernverkehrs-logistic.de/";"Neu"));** 
}
```

Furthermore what I ask myself. Is there a way to test a link in a script that he can get the last missing data from C20 via a button and then link to the website?

Help is very much appreciated. I'm completely new to the area.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0qtD.png) As here in the pictures, the ticks in the boxes are inside. But with my script I want to remove the tick so that there are only the empty boxes. And the range would be: K22: L32.

Sorry for the bad translation. Since I can't speak English myself, I had to do it via Google Translate.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here: `Is there a way to test a link in a script that he can get the last missing data from C20 via a button and then link to the website?`. Can you rephrase it somehow?

Comment: If I have the link: https://www.worldoftrucks.com/en/profile/ in the script, it should be from cell C20 of the profile sheet: 1911658 in the back and the page in the standard browser should open in the address bar , which is here: https://www.worldoftrucks.com/en/profile/1911658 inside.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have this hyperlink in `C20`? What do you want to `test`? What `missing data`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I'll let the point out. Do not know how to explain what I mean and what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `setFormula` instead of `setValue`:

```js
sheet.getRange('C16').setFormula('=HYPERLINK("https://erfurter-fernverkehrs-logistic.de/";"Neu")');
```

Also, you don't need to repeat this every time. You only have to do it once:

```js
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

#### Reference:

- [Range.setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help. That works with the hyperlink.

Comment: @NicoleSophie you're most welcome. If your problem was solved, please consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by [clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.

Comment: Now that I know I'm going to hook up.

Comment: @NicoleSophie `How do you get it with the hooks on the side like this. That the script command is in its own inner window`: I'm very sorry, I really don't understand what you mean here.